# В чем смысл матричного умножения?

Tags: матрицы, графика

В чем преимущество матричного умножения перед обычным в графике? Разве не быстрее для поворота точки на плоскости пощитать `x=x∗cos(angle)−y∗sin(angle)` & `y=x∗sin(angle)+y∗cos(angle)` вместо умножения огромных матриц 3х3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поворота матрица содержит ненулевые члены только в верхнем квадрате, и соответственно четыре полезных умножения и два сложения будет использоваться. Но матрицы аффинного преобразования могут содержать все 6 компонентов при использовании поворота, растяжения, масштабирования, сдвига, и тогда указанным выражением не отделаешься. Да взять хоть поворот вокруг определенной точки.

Заметьте, что никто не заставляет всегда выполнять покомпонентное умножение третьего столбца (0 0 1), умножение вектора на аффинную матрицу может эту часть игнорировать.

Таким образом, польза в универсальности. Если вы знаете, что у вас только одно конкретное преобразование используется - делайте сокращённую версию.